# LeanModal overlay seems to cover the modal itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

Hi there, I've downloaded [LeanModal](http://leanmodal.finelysliced.com.au/), but whenever I show the modal, it seems the overlay is applying to even the modal itself.

I assumed it was a z-index fix, but it seems that (when looking in chrome dev tools) that the z-index is being applied after the fact by leanmodal, and the CSS is ignored.

```
#lean_overlay {
position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    display: none;
}

// can't get it to sit above the overlay
#popup {
    z-index: 150;       // it looks like it's being overwritten in dev tools
    width: 600px;
    padding: 30px;
    display: none;
    background: #FFF;
}
```

`$("#i").leanModal();`

Anyone else run into this?
Thanks

Comment: So... what is it getting overwritten with? Can't you just lower the z-index for the overlay?

Comment: Did you try giving it a `z-index` during initialising? example: `$("#popup").leanModal({ z-index : 11000, ..... });`

Comment: The z-index for overlay seems to always be higher, even in the example it's less than the modal.

And changing the vals during initialization didn't seem to have any effect :(

Comment: According to the LeanModal docs, it shouldn't set any CSS at all on initialisation, hence if it doesn't work, you probably have other JS or CSS overwriting or changing what is needed. I would test it with bare minimum - comment out all other JS, make sure your CSS more or less only contains the leanmodal-rules, and test again, to see if it works.